# typehinting: method should accept any $arg that is an object

Tags: php, oop, php-5.3, type-hinting

I have a class 'Collection', which has an add method.  The add method should only accept objects. So this is the desired behaviour:

```
$x=5;//arbitrary non-object
$obj=new Foo; //arbitrary object

$collection=new Collection;
$collection->add($obj); //should be acceptable arg, no matter the actual class
$collection->add($x); //should throw an error because $x is not an object
```

According to the PHP manual, one can typehint methods by prefacing the `$arg` with a class name.  Since all PHP classes are children of `stdClass`, I figured this method signature would work:

```
public function add(stdClass $obj);
```

But it fails with "Argument must be an instance of stdClass".

If I change the signature to a parent class defined by me, then it works:

```
class Collection {
  public function add(Base $obj){
    //do stuff
  }
}

$collection->add($foo); //$foo is class Foo which is an extension of Base
```

Does anyone know how to type hint for a generic object?

Comment: `assert(is_object($arg));` is all you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike Java's `Object` class, PHP **does not have a base class for objects**. Objects do not inherit `stdClass`: it's a default object implementation, not a base class. So, unfortunately, you can't type hint for all objects in PHP. You have to do something like:

```
class MyClass {
    public function myFunc($object) {
        if (!is_object($object))
             throw new InvalidArgumentException(__CLASS__.'::'.__METHOD__.' expects parameter 1 to be object");
    }
}
```

Luckily, PHP already defines the `InvalidArgumentException` class for that purpose.

Comment: +1 for `InvalidArgumentException`. Just a note, it's only available if SPL is loaded.

Comment: You can also write `__METHOD__` instead of `MyClass::myFunc` in your exception string.

Comment: True. Fortunately, SPL is loaded by default since 5.0.0. I can't see why someone would disable it, it's so useful.

Answer (score 4):

There is no root class in PHP. Objects don't even inherit from `stdClass`:

```
class Foo {}
var_dump(new Foo instanceof stdClass); // bool(false)
var_dump(get_parent_class(new Foo));   // bool(false)
```

Apparently there is no known way in PHP to type hint for `object` even though `object` is a data type in PHP (like `array`), and typecasting to `object` yields a `stdClass` object:

```
echo get_class((object) "string"); // stdClass
```

I guess as a workaround you could tell the method to throw an exception or die with a fatal error if `is_object($obj)` returns false.

Comment: I figured since you can instantiate stdClass, it must be the base class for all objects. Learn something new every day. I wonder why PHP decided to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing is, that PHP is still a dynamic language, and type hints are just that: hints. I think you will have to fall back to the old [is_object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) or similar methods and throw a custom exception.

```
class Collection {
  public function add(Base $obj){
    if(!is_object($obj))
    throw new Exception("Parameter must be an object");
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 7.2 there is now an `object` type hint. You can simply do

```
class Collection {
  public function add(object $obj){
    //do stuff
  }
}
```