# Simple Objects in PHP question [newbie]

Tags: php, oop, object

I know you can create an array like this:

```
$a = array();
```

and append new name value pairs to it like thus:

```
$a['test'] = 'my new value';
```

It is even possible to omit the first line, although bad practice!

I find objects easier to read and understand, so what I've done is taken the array of name value pairs and cast it  into an object:

```
$a = (object)$a;
```

Thus I can access the parameters:

```
$a->test;
```

It seems wasteful for the extra overhead of creating an Array to start with, is it possible to simply create an object and then somehow just add the name value pairs to it in a similar way as I would do the array?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the [`stdClass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php) class is designed for just that.

```
$a = new stdClass;
$a->test = 'my new value';
```

You can think of it as being akin to the following JavaScript code:

```
var a = {};
a.test = 'my new value';
```

In fact, if you had some PHP code that received data as JSON, running `json_decode()` on the data results in a `stdClass` object with the included properties.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `stdClass` object for that:

```
$a = new stdClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple even without stdclass. You can simply do

```
class obj{}
$obj = new obj;
$obj->foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: Thanks - i thought it probably would be as simple as that!

Comment: Uh, you're missing `$obj = new obj;` between the two statements

Comment: @Thariama: You forgot to create an instance of obj. `$obj = new obj;` Actually the class is futile. It's an implicit extension of stdClass and not adding anything to it. Therefore it's just another entry in types table at runtime and potentially confusing developers.

Comment: @rik: [`obj` does not extend `stdClass`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218693/typehinting-method-should-accept-any-arg-that-is-an-object), not even implicitly.

Comment: @BoltClock: It does. `class obj extends stdClass {}` is semantically the same. Of course you have to use the correct type hints. But that does not mean the classes are different.

Comment: @rik: In that case, why does `class obj {} var_dump(new obj instanceof stdClass);` say `bool(false)`, but `class obj2 extends stdClass {} var_dump(new obj2 instanceof stdClass);` say `bool(true)`?

Comment: @rik: Fine if you consider two separately classes with identical members *semantically* like, but saying that all classes inherit from `stdClass` is just wrong. A class only inherits from it if you say so in code. It's not a root class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **stdClass** for this.

```
$object = new StdClass;  
$object->foo = 'bar';
```